# mysql - Not able to create table error in foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nm`.`list_activities` (
  `activity_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `activity_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
  `activity_type_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`activity_id`, `activity_type_id`)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_list_activities_log`
    FOREIGN KEY (`activity_id`)
    REFERENCES `nm`.`log` (`activity_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nm`.`log` (
  `date_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `activity_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`date_id`, `activity_id`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Not able to create `list_activities` table,It display the error message

> Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

in mysql

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have composite primary key and you are creating FK only on key one column and so nothing but creating a partial functional dependency.

```
PRIMARY KEY (`date_id`, `activity_id`)

   FOREIGN KEY (`activity_id`)
    REFERENCES `nm`.`log` (`activity_id`)
```

You will have to create a FK referencing both the key column to solve this issue. Change your FK definition to be

```
   FOREIGN KEY (`activity_id`, `activity_type_id`)
    REFERENCES `nm`.`log` (`activity_id`, `date_id`)
```

Comment: but i need to create FK in date table that reffer to date_id in this log table.and one for list_activities that i mention above, Date table is created. thanks

Comment: but it will reffer to date_id coloumn of log table . activity_type_id is diffrent that is reffer by another table.

Comment: Since PK is pair, you have to create a foreign key that refers to two fields as well. You may want to consider your schema and how you are normalizing these tables.